# How is stellar going to help the underbanked?

Tags: banks

I see a lot about helping the underbanked, but in practice, how will stellar actually benefit the underbanked?

Answer (score 4):

Straight from https://www.stellar.org/about/mandate/
I added the actions Stellar has taken in parentheses.

---

### Responsibilities

To promote global financial access, literacy, and inclusion, SDF shall:

- Develop and maintain a secure and low cost global transaction network “Stellar Network” and protocol “Stellar Protocol” that is high quality, open-source, and publicly accessible to everyone. (they reduced the wallet minimum balance from 20 to 1)
- Develop and maintain publicly accessible tools and services to support the Stellar Network and its users. (using JavaScript SDK and easy to learn code while running the Stellar Laboratory)
- Provide guidance and direction for the Stellar ecosystem.
- Promote adoption of Stellar as a worldwide payment standard. (partner with IBM and made a ATM for XLM)
- Distribute the native currency of the Stellar ecosystem, lumens, to the world to expand the reach of the network and create a more inclusive digital economy. (Stellar has a direct signup program)
- Create and support technical and non-technical partnerships and educational initiatives to boost digital financial literacy and development efforts at the institutional and community level.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding it's similar to the claim Bitcoin makes, removing the current barriers to banking, where people would/could not have a bank account but they may have a mobile phone allowing them access to a mobile money account.

- It allows you to have an account without needing valid ID or documentation like birth certs.
- Lower transaction fees & faster transfer times.
- The last point is especially useful for remittance, sending money from one county to a home country to help family.
- Where physical bank access itself can be difficult.

Andreas Antonopolous has spoken quite a bit on how Bitcoin can help the unbanked and I would say most is applicable to Stellar. [Andreas Antonopoulos What Bitcoin Means For Unbanked Economies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLPvEP6BSGE).

> To solve these problems, we need financial infrastructure that supports the kind of
>   organic growth and innovation we’ve seen from the Internet, yet still ensures the integrity
>   of financial transactions. Historically, we have relied on high barriers to entry to
>   ensure integrity. We trust established financial institutions and do our best to regulate
>   them. But this exclusivity conflicts with the goal of organic growth. Growth demands
>   new, innovative participants, who may possess only modest financial and computing
>   resources.
>   We need a worldwide financial network open to anyone, so that new organizations
>   can join and extend financial access to unserved communities. The challenge for such
>   a network is ensuring participants record transactions correctly. With a low barrier
>   to entry, users won’t trust providers to police themselves. With worldwide reach,
>   providers won’t all trust a single entity to operate the network. A compelling alternative
>   is a decentralized system in which participants together ensure integrity by
>   agreeing on the validity of one another’s transactions. Such agreement hinges on a
>   mechanism for worldwide consensus.
>   [The Stellar Consensus Protocol](https://www.stellar.org/papers/stellar-consensus-protocol.pdf)

---

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the benefits that bitcoin/other cryptocurrencies provide, stellar also allows underbanked people to forget currency altogether. For example, if someone has credits for cows, stellar can find a path through "anchors" that can allow them to instantly exchange a cow credit for an equivalent amount of seed credits.